# type changed using wrapt package

Tags: python-3.x, variable-assignment, static-members

This

```
<class 'assign.A'>
<class 'BoundFunctionWrapper'>
```

is printed by the following code:

```
from wrapt import FunctionWrapper


class A(FunctionWrapper):
    A = None

    def __init__(self, f):
        super(A, self).__init__(f, self.wrapper)

    def wrapper(self, wrapped, instance, args, kwargs):
        return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)


@A
def f():
    pass


print(type(f))
A.A = f
print(type(A.A))
```

The type changes **only** if `f` is assigned to a static variable of a class. I would have expected the type to remain `A`.
How can that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked that and this would be the default behavior in Python 2 and not in Python 3:

```
>>> class X(object): # Python 2
    def g():pass
>>> X.g
<unbound method X.g>
```

Reasons for the behavior of wrapt:

1. The same module is also existent in Python 2.
2. I see no check in the code of `wrapt.wrappers` that creates different behavior form 2 to 3 for this special case.

### Explanation

The `__get__` behavior changed.

**Python 2:**

```
>>> class X(object):
    def g():pass

>>> X.g
<unbound method X.g>
>>> class B: # error: Must inherit form object (see comments)
    def __get__(self, *args):
        print(args)


>>> X.b = B()
>>> X.b
<__main__.B instance at 0x029C0440>
```

**Python 3:**

```
>>> class X(object):
    def g():pass

>>> X.g
<function g at 0x030430C0>
>>> class B:
    def __get__(self, *args):
        print(args)


>>> X.b = B()
>>> X.b
(None, <class 'X'>)
```

**Recommendation**

1. I would say that this may be a bug. According to [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wrapt)
   , `wrapt` longs for correctness. So, this should be discussed, I guess. Please open an issue on [github](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/wrapt/issues) and link this question (Tell me if I should do it).
2. Use the attribute `__bound_function_wrapper__` to create an own wrapper for bound methods. Code that shows context in `wrapt.wrappers`:

   ```
   class FunctionWrapper(_FunctionWrapperBase):

       __bound_function_wrapper__ = BoundFunctionWrapper
   ```

   So, if you really want to create an own wrapper class you can do that:

   ```
   class OwnBoundWrapper(wrapt.BoundFunctionWrapper): 
       # additional code here
   A.__bound_function_wrapper__ = OwnBoundWrapper
   ```

Comment: thank you - I opened a ticket:
https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/wrapt/issues/45


However to be honest I have no idea how to proceed from the stub you're giving in 2. yet

Comment: The Python 2 example in this answer is not correct. Class 'B' should derive from 'object' else it will not act as a descriptor. The original behaviour is exactly what I would expect. At a conference at the moment so don't have the time to give a more detailed explanation. OP should explain if there is a particular issue they are trying to solve and if not working as one would expect, what problem it is causing.

Comment: Some further commentary added to the issue in the wrapt github repo.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that this is (mostly) expected behavior.

You can read [this](http://wrapt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/wrappers.html?highlight=__bound_function_wrapper__#custom-function-wrappers) for more details, but basically, as you mentioned the fact that `FunctionWrapper` is a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) (has a `__get__` method) is what is causing the behavior you observe.

The descriptor protocol is used to return methods instead of just bare functions when you do something like

```
some_var = instance.method
```

It is true that python 2 and 3 have different behavior when an instance method is retrieved from a class:

python3:

```
In [1]: class Test:
...:     def a(self):
...:         pass
...:

In [2]: Test.a
Out[2]: <function __main__.Test.a>
```

python2:

```
In [1]: class Test:
...:     def a(self):
...:         pass
...:

In [2]: Test.a
Out[2]: <function __main__.Test.a>
```

Where python2 returns an unboundmethod, python3 simply returns the function. Howevever, there could be some reason that one might want to still decorate things when they are accessed on the class. An example of doing something like this would be creating a hybrid property that has one name, but different behavior on the class thant it has for instances of the class.